# Adding custom validator to jquery validate plugin not displaying error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I couldn't find a similar solution to the issue I'm facing on SO. I'm using jquery validate plugin to validate a form. I've added a couple of custom validator methods to validate a drop down and another for validating a text box. The drop down validation works fine, but the text box validation only 'partially' works. I say 'partial' because the actual validation part works but the error message that is supposed to be displayed, does not display. The field in question is the id3 text field, and it's associated javascript.

This is my html:

---

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="paymentInformation" id="paymentInformation" action="verifyOrder.cfm" method="post" role="form">

<div class="form-group">
<fieldset class="col-sm-12">

  <!-- Row 1 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="booktype" class="col-6 col-form-label">
        Book Type *
      </label>
      <select class="custom-select col-4" id="booktype" name="booktype">
        <option selected value="">Select book type</option>
        <option value="val1">E-BOOK</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="id2" class="col-6 col-form-label">
        Number
      </label>
      <input type="form-control" placeholder="Number" type="text" id="id2" name="id2" class="col-10">
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /Row 1 -->
  <!-- Row 2 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="firstname" class="col-6 col-form-label">
        First Name *
      </label>
      <input type="form-control" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="col-12" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="id2" class="col-6 col-form-label">
        Book Name
      </label>
      <input type="form-control" placeholder="Book Name" type="text" id="id3" name="id3" class="col-10">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /Row 2 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="lastname" class="col-6 col-form-label">
        Last Name *
      </label>
      <input type="form-control" type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="col-12" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /Row 2 -->
  <label for="description" class="col-10 col-form-label">
    Country description
  </label>
  <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="4" class="form-control txtarea-rounded"></textarea>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="col-sm-6">Countries: </label>
    <br />
    <label class="form-check-label col-10">
      <input class="form-check-input col-10" type="checkbox" name="usa" value="Y">USA
      <br />
      <input class="form-check-input col-10" type="checkbox" name="uk" value="Y"> UK
    </label>
  </div>

</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="hideDiv">
<input type="submit" name=btnSubmit value="PROCEED TO THE NEXT STEP &#xf054;" class="blueButton">
</div>
</form>
```

---

Here is my javascript: (Problem custom rule is commented in CAPS)

---

```
var authorlist = [{"AUTHOR":"DONNA 
EDWARDS","COUNTRY":"USA","REGION":"MIDWEST"},{"AUTHOR":"EMERALD 
JONES","COUNTRY":"UK","REGION":"EU"},
{"AUTHOR":"SHAKESPEARE","COUNTRY":"UK","REGION":"EU"}];

function checkName(){
    var nameIsValid = true;
    var nametocheck = $("#id3").val();
  $.each(authorlist, function(index, val){
  //console.log(val.AUTHOR);
  if(val.AUTHOR.toUpperCase() == nametocheck.toUpperCase()){
    //console.log(val.AUTHOR);
    nameIsValid = false;
  return false;
 }
 });
 return nameIsValid;
 }

$("#id3").on("blur", function(){
  if(!checkName()){
  //display error: This Book name already exists!
 }
  else{
  //remove error message
 }
  console.log("The name entered is valid: " + checkName());
 });


 function checkForm() {
   var formIsValid = checkName() && $("#paymentInformation").valid();
   if (formIsValid) {
     $(".hideDiv").show();
   } else {
     $(".hideDiv").hide();
    }
  }

 $("#booktype").on("change", function() {
    checkForm();
  });

 $("#paymentInformation").on("keyup", function() {
    checkForm();
  });

 // first custom rule
 $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg) {
   return arg !== value;
  }, "Value must not equal arg.");

  //2ND CUSTOM RULE - THIS RULE PARTIALLY WORKS, BUT ERROR DOES NOT DISPLAY
 $.validator.addMethod("booknameExists", function(value,element,arg){

  }, "Book name must not pre-exist");

 $.validator.setDefaults({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    highlight: function(element) {
     $(element).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
   unhighlight: function(element) {
     $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
   },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if (element.parent('.input-group').length || element.prop('type') === 
      'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
         error.insertAfter(element.parent());
       } else {
         error.insertAfter(element);
       }
     }
 });

 $("#paymentInformation").validate({
   rules: {
   'booktype': {
     valueNotEquals: ""
    },
   'firstname': {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 200
    },
   'lastname': {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 200
    },
   'id3': {
     required: true,
     maxlength: 100,
     booknameExists: false

   }
  },
 messages: {
'booktype': {
  valueNotEquals: "Select a book type.",
},
'firstname': {
  required: "Enter your First Name.",
  maxlength: "Your First Name cannot exceed 200 characters"
},
'lastname': {
  required: "Enter your Last Name.",
  maxlength: "Your Last Name cannot exceed 200 characters"
},

 //THE FIRST 2 STANDARD BUILT IN ERROR MESSAGES ARE DISPLAYED CORRECTLY,
 //BUT THE LAST CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE - booknameExists - DOES NOT
'id3': {
  required: "Book name is required.",
  maxlength: "Book name cannot exceed 200 characters",
  booknameExists: "Book name already exists!"
}
}
});
```

---

The css is in the fiddle but for the sake of completeness, here it is:

---

```
 .hideDiv {
    display: none;
  }

.has-error {
   color: red;
 }
```

Here is the link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0puehapu/

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing.  If you're going to use the jQuery Validate plugin, then you don't need to write all the manual validation functions that trigger on blur and add/remove messages... the plugin automatically takes care of all this tedium.

Comment: @Sparky - I believe I need this custom validator for the following scenario: I need to validate the value entered in a text field(let's call it textVal), by looping through a json object and making sure that textVal doesn't exist in the json object. If textVal already exists in the json object, then I need to flag it with an error message, letting the user know that since textVal already exists, they need to enter a different value. From what I understand,jquery validate plugin can check for required, minlength,maxlength etc,but something like the above has to be custom validation. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you may misunderstand what the plugin is supposed to do.   It checks the fields against the rules, triggered by various events, applies classes, shows messages, etc., all automatically.  Create custom methods when a rule doesn't already exist... like you need to make a field's value match certain criteria not covered by an existing rule; for example, a cellular phone number format from an obscure country.  Even then, the plugin still automatically takes care of showing/hiding messages and applying classes.

Comment: Hint: Lookup and use `.addMethod()` for creating new rules.

Comment: @Sparky - I'll be darned! I thought I had that in the fiddle up top but for some reason fiddle didn't save it and thereby didn't show it. Here's one I've created again w/ the .addMethod() but it's the same problem - If you enter all the required fields, and then enter 'shakespeare' in the 'Book Name' field, you'll see that console shows that since 'shakespeare' is already an existing value in json object (authorlist), nameIsValid is shown as false (correctly). But, the associated error message - booknameExists - is not displayed. https://jsfiddle.net/damon_matt/fsLza6m0/

Comment: You have the `booknameExists` rule set to `false`... this means the rule is not being used at all.  When you create a rule with `.addMethod()`, you have to set it to `true` (or a parameter) if you want to use it.  Setting any rule to `false` effectively and totally disables it.   Regardless, you also have ***no function*** inside of this `.addMethod("booknameExists")`... what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Sparky - I tried setting booknameExists to 'true' but didn't help. I guess I was just trying everything I could think of, hoping something would work. As for the function inside the .addMethod, that is the part I'm struggling with. Essentially, what I'm trying to do is to make sure that checkName() function returns true. checkName() checks the value in the id3 textbox and makes sure it's not already contained in the authorlist json object. If the id3 textbox's value is already in the authorlist json object, the nameIsValid value is set to false, otherwise it's set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this figured out. My custom validator was missing a single line of code. This is how my custom validator looks now, after the bug fix:

```
$.validator.addMethod("booknameExists", function(value){
   return checkName();
 }, "Book name must not pre-exist");
```

The missing piece was: return checkName();
Not having messed w/ validate plugin for >10yrs, it was a re-learning process, and I'm not a college grad anymore! Thx to @Sparky for his efforts - will be upvoting his comment.

(PS: for anyone looking for the complete code, the jsfiddle that I posted in my reply to Sparky has all of it - the only change is the above snippet)

Comment: Why not just use the same logic inside of the `.addMethod()`, instead of the whole external function?